# Cmd Line Arg like %1 and %s to get ALL args passed to program and not only the first

Tags: batch-file

I have a program that deals with command line args being sent to the program by being executed by Run.
Sometimes I need to send more than one arg, and then the program crashes. And I noticed that it only takes the first one, and I know that it is a problem with the %1 or %s or %l that I use.

What is the right arg to send?

Comment: what language, we aren't mind readers ...

Comment: @Jarrod: Chances are 99% that it's for batch files, hence I just edited the question tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption: batch scripting

Use `%*` to get all arguments.

`%1` to `%9` works for the first nine arguments. You can use `shift` to get those after `%9`.